# ¿Cómo crear una LocalDB en Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

He visto varios videos que crean una base de datos Local con Visual Studio pero en versiones anteriores, no se si habrán removido esa opción, pero lo cierto es que he instalado de todo y tratado miles de cosas sin resultado alguno.

Para empezar he instalado SQL Server (ultima version) junto a su Manager y su incrustacion dentro del Visual Studio 2017, me di cuenta luego de mucho leer y mirar videos que SQL Server no sirve para crear bases de datos embebidas o portables, pero si funciona el SQL Compact 4.0, por lo que lo instalé desde la pagina de Microsoft junto a su Toolbox que supuestamente me lo integra al Visual Studio, pero no, aun no veo la opcion como sale en los videos para elegir BASE DE DATOS LOCAL desde la pestaña DATA en Visual C#.

Sinceramente es bastante frustrante esto y recurro a ustedes como último recurso.

Soy bastante nuevo en todo esto de las bases de datos

Comment: Usa una base mas simple, como sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una `db local` al proyecto tienes que agregar un item que cree la `.sdf`

El primer paso seria verificar si instalaste

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

La administracion la realizas

[SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension for Visual Studio](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox)

desde esta deberias poder crear la db

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien deberias poder agregar el item al proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]